Every variety of the form $\operatorname{Proj}A$ is a closed subscheme of $\mathbb P^m_k$ for some $m$
So a while ago I proved that every closed subscheme of a (quasicompact) projective scheme is a projective scheme (i.e. of the form $\operatorname{Proj A}$).  I often hear the classical definition that projective varieties over $k$ are closed subschemes of $\mathbb P^n_k$ for some $n$, so I would hope that this also true with the more modern definitions.
To be precise, I take a variety to be a scheme $X$ over a field $k$ which is reduced, separated, and of finite type. In particular, a projective variety is a variety is which of the form $\operatorname{Proj}A$. I suspect that I could potentially relax the reduced and separated conditions, and get a similar result, but I don't care that much about that.
Let $X$ be a projective variety, so that $X=\operatorname{Proj}A$. In particular $X$ is Noetherian, and there is a finite open cover of the form $\operatorname{Spec}(A_{f_i})_0$ for some fixed graded ring $A$, and $f_i$ homogenous of positive degree, $0\leq i\leq m$. Each $(A_{f_i})_0$ should be isomorphic to $k[x_0,\dots, x_{n_i}]/I_i$ by finite type. Without loss of generality, I can take $n_i=n$ for all $i$ because there is some maximum $n_j$ and for any $n_i<n_j$ I can quotient $k[x_0,\dots, x_{n_j}]$ out by $\langle x_{n_i+1},\dots, x_{n_j},I_i\rangle$ to ge the same $k$ algebra.
I suspect I should be able to then embed $X$ into $\mathbb P^{n+1}_k$ by defining local maps, but I can't quite see how to do this, and how the gluing should work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Proj behaves in enough funny ways that this is not true without (potentially many) further assumptions. For instance, let $R$ be a ring, and let $R[t]$ be the graded ring where $R$ has degree $0$ and $t$ has degree $1$ - then $\operatorname{Proj} R[t] \cong \operatorname{Spec} R$ (ref), so for instance if we take $R=k[x]$, then $\operatorname{Proj} k[x,t]$ where $\deg x = 0$ and $\deg t=1$ is exactly $\Bbb A^1_k$, which is not projective over $k$. This is also unfixable via putting a condition on $A_0$, since Proj is insensitive to alterations of $A_0$ (ref).
The more standard definition of a projective variety $X$ over $k$ is one where the morphism $X\to \operatorname{Spec} k$ is projective; there are then a few different choices of what "projective" mean (see Stacks 01W7) which are all equivalent when working over a field (and more generally, all equivalent when working over a base scheme which admits an ample invertible sheaf).

I see...Vakil defines a projective scheme over $A$ to be $\operatorname{Proj}S$ where $S$ is a graded ring finitely generated by $A=S_0$; this seems to eliminate the grading issue in your counter example, but you say $\operatorname{Proj}$ is insensitive to alterations of $A_0$. Does forcing the zero degree elements to be a field not somehow fix this problem?

Take the same ring but the $0$-graded piece to $k$ will give you the same Proj. If you  add the conditions that $S_0=A$ and $S$ is finitely generated over $S_0$, then you can prove that there is a closed immersion $\operatorname{Proj} S\to\Bbb P^n_A$ for some $n$; but those assumptions aren't in your question. (If you would like to add these assumptions, I would recommend asking a new question, assuming it hasn't already been covered here on MSE.)

thank you, I will ask a new question.

It seems from Corollary 5.16 in Hartshorne that we need $A$ to be finitely generated over $A_1$ as an $A_0$ algebra. Also I asked a new question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4996730/every-projective-shceme-over-a-is-a-closed-subscheme-of-mathbb-pn-a

The fact that $\mathrm{Proj}\,A$ is covered by $\mathrm{Spec}\,A_{f_i}$ plainly means that any homogeneous prime ideal not containing the irrelevant ideal of $A$ must not contain every $f_i$.
So, any prime ideal containing all of the $f_i$ is irrelevant. Hence as topological spaces, one has
$$\mathrm{Proj}\,A=\mathrm{Proj}(k[f_0,…,f_m]).$$
The latter is definitely a closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^m_k$.
Further, a commonly known fact is that given a Noetherian scheme $S$ and a closed set $Z\subseteq S$, there is only one reduced closed subscheme of $S$ with underlying topological space $Z$.
Since both above schemes are reduced, it follows that in fact,
$$\mathrm{Proj}\,A=\mathrm{Proj}(k[f_0,…,f_m])$$
as schemes, so that $\mathrm{Proj}\,A$ is a closed subscheme of $\mathbb P^m_k$.

For the commonly known fact I use, Noetherianity might not even be required actually. I’ll leave it there to be safe.

This answer is not correct as currently written - for example, when $A=k[x,t]$ with $\deg x = 0$ and $\deg t =1$, then $\operatorname{Proj} A$ is covered by $D_+(t)$, but $\operatorname{Proj} A$ is not in any sense the same as $\operatorname{Proj} k[t]$. Additionally, even if this were the case, the claim that $\operatorname{Proj}(k[f_0,\cdots,f_m])$ is a closed subscheme of $\Bbb P^m_k$ requires more work - what if not all of the $f_i$ have the same degree? (This of course can be made to work with more argument, but that argument isn't present.)

Thank you for the counterexample. You are right, I should have given more thought to my answer.
